# Directed Graphs Types

Tags: graph-theory

I'm trying to figure out if there is any type of classification of such a graph as we have below. As you can see, 1, 3 and 5 act like a hub.

I'm doing a college project where I need to program a graph with 40 hubs (all connected among them).

Additionally, each hub has n+1 vertices that don't connect with the other 39 hubs. Is there any name for a graph like that?

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you're interested in [maximal cliques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)).